# inference of an undefined array

Tags: typescript, type-inference

```js
interface Foo {
  a: number;
  b: string;
}

function augment<T>() {
  return <A extends keyof T>(actions?: A[]) => {
    const C = class {
      // some code here that is irrelevant for my issue
    };

    return C as unknown as new () => InstanceType<typeof C> & Pick<T, A>;
  };
}

const Class = augment<Foo>()(["a", "b"]);
const instance: InstanceType<typeof Class> = new Class();

//  instance.a and instance.b are available, as expected

const Class2 = augment<Foo>()([]);
const instance2: InstanceType<typeof Class2> = new Class2();

//  instance2.a and instance.b do no exist

const Class3 = augment<Foo>()();
const instance3: InstanceType<typeof Class3> = new Class3();

//  instance3.a is available even if I didn't pass any actions :-(
```

In `augment`, I'm using the `actions` parameter in order to infer the `A` type.

It works with any properties of `Foo` but when I don't pass some actions, it's like the inference type deduces that `A` is `keyof T`.

I know I could pass an empty array but I really want to have to possibility to pass no actions for my function, is there a way to do that?

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgUQG4FMB2NkmDGdKOAXzgDMoIQ4AidDbAZ1oChXhsjyBDAY3RwAYhAiJWcODwBccTAFcQAIyIBuCXCWymMKJwDm6ku3LzMfGMAiYp8-SCwwAPABUAfAAoAlOMlR0MPJQNk4AgnDoAB6EmAAmTHAA1ugAnhDkcO4e-JbWTAD8sqEA2gC6PgC8br6ScHx58ADCcBV1ADY8TAlRMfEojDh4BESIJOoafgFBNs2dcGaJmBAA7jZzmOjLcN4t1QCSmDo85uguKWDoTjDn6OlwjdUAZHAACsB8ia4ANHChbuqSMasYyseqHJodLotWz2RxOEQQTxeDzFWg8Wg-WhKWjldRgnRwThHE6yA7EgRnC5XG53RqQpjVVobLZ0zpMbzqIkwY4CAB0PFUcAA9EK5GIiFRiEzoCAeG0OOCeeheUpBSKxREoJLoUsoLL5ax1YBeDcAsjuExUnflSOLm8nKpRSfxSVA8YAdJRtdA-OZRC4WdCxdj4iFsgBM0J4dgc2HhoiRKNxoIatu5J1DpItFJu1IutPpocZck293zHIVdtD-LVool0B1Mrl5dTAkrquFNa1delesbhtFppTSsrPGtsUHlodsTESwikWAOiDydZXQAzBGo3CEfGvHjk1ylSuM3bKZdrrmMsumCvC8yS2yV2X9ycV1X23A9gByMdtYDJOAwMR9ACTVtQACyIdAmwPFVq3fL84B-P8ALgID4FrYhwP8dhjUAOR3xwEF8R3nZ1XXdT0IkYQkMj2OBYmAWJMA-eAwDZa0UikCwrEOOBpAAWg8IA)

Comment: If you explicitly specify a type using `augment<Foo>()()` with no parameters, you still get a `Foo` object. Specifying an empty array *still* gets you a `Foo` object.

Comment: No, I've added a typescript playground link to show it

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NBJgnN) specifying `never` as the default generic type argument meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks, that what I missed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because if `A` cannot be inferred, TypeScript will default to using its generic constraint type. Fortunately, you can override this behavior by providing a default. In the case that `A` cannot be inferred because nothing was passed for `actions`, you can default to `never`:

```
function augment<T>() {
  return <A extends keyof T = never>(actions?: A[]) => {
//                         ~~~~~~~~ defaults to `never` if `A` cannot be inferred
    const C = class extends EventEmitter {};

    return C as unknown as new () => InstanceType<typeof C> & Pick<T, A>;
  };
}
```

Then, in the third example, you will get errors, since it is now using `Pick<Foo, never>`:

```
const Class3 = augment<Foo>()();
const instance3: InstanceType<typeof Class3> = new Class3();
instance3.a; // error
instance3.b; // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgUQG4FMB2NkmDGdKOAXzgDMoIQ4AidDbAZ1oChXhsjyBDAY3RwAYhAiJWcODwBccTAFcQAIyIBuCXCWymMKJwDm6ku3LzMfGMAiYp8-SCwwAPABUAfAAoAlOMlR0MPJQNk4AgnDoAB6EmAAmTHAA1ugAnhDkcC5wALxyDESe-JbWTAD8sqEA2gC6PtluvpJwfCXwAMI5zQA2PEwJUTHxKIw4eAREiCTqGn4BQTYdvXBmiZgQAO42S5jo63DeOQ0Akpg6POboLilg6E4w1+jpcG0NAGRwAArAfImuADRwUJudSSKasYysFqndo9PqdHh2BzYJwiCCeLweSq0Hi0AG0JS0WrqKE6OCcM4XWQnCkCK43O4PJ5tWFMBq5HZ7Zm9JjedTkmDnAQAOh4qjgAHpxXIxEQqMR2dAQDwuhxoYL0EKlGLJdKIlA5Z01lAlSrWDrALwbgFkdslqi4iqRxG00jVKKT+KSoHjAHpKLroAFLKI3CzoWLsEkw7kAJnhiMcKNE6MxRMhrSdAouUapttpDwZNyZLKjbLynKLvNVzqjIu1Utl0ENiuVlYzAmrWoldf1DYVxubZqlVvT6urPAdsWHdtdsTEawikWAOnDaa5fQAzLH7PHUUmvMS0-z1Wvs866bd7gWMqumGuSxzniy1xXDxc1zXO3AjgByCddYDJOAYDEfQAj1A0AAsiHQFsj01WtPx-OA-wAoC4BA+B62ISD-HYHUIESHgUiAA)